# Notepad++ Regex reorder strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

i'm working on a project that requires reordering some text. I want to use n++ with regex. Here's what I want to accomplish:

change
 
**G0 X28.5 Y5 S0

G1 X74 S255**
to
**M42 P11 S0

G0 X28.5 Y5

M42 P11 S255

G1 X74**
So basically not changing anything in part from **G** all the way to **the space before S** and moving the **S** value one line up adding the **M42 P11** before it. Also there is sometimes the Y value, and both X and Y can contain dots in their values. I would really appreciate if somebody could show me how to do it using regex. Thank you.

Comment: Have you had sometime dealing with it? Have you tried anything?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want something like this

```
([ .\w]+)(S\d+$)$
```

and replace the match with `M42 P11 \2\n\1` in `Notepad++`

Output is,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex:

```
(G\d+\sX(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*)(?:\sY\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?)\s(S\d+)
```

and replace with:

```
M42 P11 \2\n\1
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rp4vHI/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this short one too, perfectly working in my editor.

Find what: `(.*)(\w\d+$)`
Replace with: `m42 p11 $2\n$1`